# Comparator 'comparing' cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, comparator

I'm trying to sort two objects by two fields. One boolean and one int. 
However I'm getting a "`cannot resolve method" on the 'comparing' method`.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyViewModel another) {
   return Comparator.comparing(MyViewModel::isEnabled)
          .thenComparingInt(MyViewModel::getPriority);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have your IDE compiler configured for Java 8 or superior sources?

Comment: hmm makes me think somehow you are not using java 8.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio. Where can I check that it is applicably configured?

Comment: You can use Java 8 language *features* (lambdas, method references) on Android (using Gradle build plugin 3.x.x). **You cannot use Java 8 language *APIs* (java.time, functional interfaces) until min SDK 26.** This means that even if you enable Java 8 compatibility your app will crash on devices running Android older than 8.0.

Comment: ohh.. that's a problem, I have to support a min skd of 14.

how can that be implemented not by java 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write the `compareTo()` method it seems you want without using Java 8 APIs:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyViewModel another) {
    int enabledComparison = Boolean.compare(isEnabled(), another.isEnabled());

    if (enabledComparison != 0) {
        return enabledComparison;
    }

    return Integer.compare(getPriority(), another.getPriority());
}
```

Unfortunately, `Boolean.compare()` and `Integer.compare()` were added in Android API 19, and you said you need to support back to 14, so you can't even use that. You have to write it all the way out by hand.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MyViewModel another) {
    int enabledComparison = compare(isEnabled(), another.isEnabled());

    if (enabledComparison != 0) {
        return enabledComparison;
    }

    return compare(getPriority(), another.getPriority());
}

private static int compare(boolean a, boolean b) {
    if (a == b) {
       return 0;
    } else if (a) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return -1;
    }
}

private static int compare(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided does work with Java 8.

And when you convert the former `comparing` params from method reference to `m -> m.isEnabled`, it will report `can't resolve method 'isEnabled' in 'Object'` just like what you describe.

Then, you can specify the class of `m` explicitly as follows to resolve it.

```
  @Override
    public int compareTo(MyViewModel another) {
       return Comparator.comparing((MyViewModel m) -> m.isEnabled)
              .thenComparingInt(MyViewModel::getPriority);
    }
```